# "not be able to do sth"

Tags: grammar

Could you please say the following sentence is correct?

> You have to be able to analyze the poem, not to be able to just
> regurgitate that.

My main question is about the second part of the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Can you please add more context and a deeper explenation of your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be concerned. I can more or less guess what you are trying to say, but the second half of the sentence has several problems. The "that" does not refer properly back to "the poem". Using "it" would be better. I think "regurgitate" has the wrong connotations. Finally, "not be able to just" is awkward.

I would not try to fix the sentence. Rewrite it completely, perhpas as two sentences.  How you do that depends on the context. Here are some possibilities:

> You have to be able to analyze the poem. Just knowing how to recite it is not enough.

or

> Just reading the poem is not enough. You should be able to analyze it.

Comment: I mean exactly what you said. Actually, I like to use "not" to negative second part of the sentence. Is it possible to say "You have to be able to analyze the poem, not just recite it."?

Answer (score 0):

### Here are some rules you should follow to understand this sentence.

> You have to be able to analyze the poem, not to be able to just regurgitate that.

---

1. Whenever possible use ellipsis to avoid repetition. In this case, you do not need to repeat the verb "to be able to". Another example of ellipsis would be.

> You have to run and you have to jump.
> This sentence should become:
> You have to run and jump.
> It isn't necessary to repeat you have to.

---

2. When referring to something specific or within the sentence you should use it. When something is abstract or outside that sentence, use that. This is not always so clear cut, but in this case:

Example of "that"

> This dog is really intelligent. We all agree on that.

"That" refers to the the idea that the dog is intelligent.

Example of "it"

> We bought a new television and are now enjoying watching it.

The "it" refers to the television, a concrete thing.

---

### In your case:

> You have to be able to analyze the poem, not to be able to just regurgitate that.

"That" refers to something concrete which is in the sentence, so it doesn't quite fit. Use "it" instead of "that".

Comment: "...not just regurgitate it" would be sufficient.

Comment: In order to emphasize, I repeated the "be able to". Is that correct?

Comment: Good question. I would say not really. In writing, it usually just feels awkward, although, I'm sure there are some situations where writers manage it.  I wouldn't recommend it to my students unless they were following an example of an experienced writer. If you want to know how to create emphasis, I would make a new post, the explanation is a bit too complex for a comment.